# Doctrine documents can not be loaded if the ID strategy is NONE

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm using Doctrine with MongoDB. Usually I don't care about the IDs but in one case I need the ID before the flush to avoid a needless roundtrip.
So I added the ID strategy "NONE" and set the ID in the constructor. 
**But after that I cannot load a document by its ID.**

Code to load a document:

```php
/* @var $userRepo DocumentRepository */
$userRepo = $managerRegistry->getRepository(User::class);
$qb = $userRepo->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->field('id')->in(['5cb6377ae0b68801bc3b1771']);
$user = $qb->getQuery()->execute()->getSingleResult();
var_dump($user instanceof User);

/* @var $userRepo DocumentRepository */
$userRepo = $managerRegistry->getRepository(User::class);
$users = $userRepo->findBy(['id' => '5cb6377ae0b68801bc3b1771']);
var_dump(count($users) === 1);

/* @var $userRepo DocumentRepository */
$userRepo = $managerRegistry->getRepository(User::class);
$user = $userRepo->find('5cb6377ae0b68801bc3b1771');
var_dump($user instanceof User);
```

(Actually false, false, false - Expected true, true, true)

Document:

```php
/**
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class User
{

    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="NONE")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = new \MongoId();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're using a string in the find calls. You need to use `MongoId` as that's what your identifier is. So:

```
/* @var $userRepo DocumentRepository */
$userRepo = $managerRegistry->getRepository(User::class);
$user = $userRepo->find(new \MongoId('5cb6377ae0b68801bc3b1771'));
```

Comment: Yes this makes sense. But I don't want to change the way to deal with the objects. So I have changed the annotation to `@ODM\Id(strategy="NONE", type="string")` and the constructor to `$this->id = (string) new \MongoId();`

It seems to work fine, but now - consequent - a string instead of an ObjectId is stored in the database. I'm not sure if there are any side effects.
If doctrine cares about id generation, an ObjectId is saved in the database but nevertheless I can query with a string. What makes doctrine different internally?

Comment: Can't tell from the top of my head but it sounds like a bug. If you could open an issue in https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm we'll investigate it